# Is it possible to place a std::array at a fixed memory address?

Tags: c++11, std

For an embedded design I want to place a C++ std::array at a specific memory address, which points to a buffer shared by hardware and software. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a loot at [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) although you would have to make some assumptions on the layout of `std::array` which are not guaranteed by the standard. Placement new will also initialize the memory, which you may not want... If you can assume the layout and alignment of `std::array`, you can simply perform a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  alignas(double) char buffer[100];
  auto parr = new (buffer) std::array<double, 3> {3.14, 15.161, 12};
  const auto & arr =  *parr; 
  std::cout << (void*) &arr << " " << (void*) buffer << "\n";
  for (auto x: arr)
    std::cout << x << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

which may give this output:

```
0x7ffcdd906770 0x7ffcdd906770
3.14 15.161 12
```

One thing to be worried about is whether the address you want to use is consistent with the alignment requirements of the data you want to hold in the array. Most likely you will be dealing with `char`s, `float`s or `int`s, so this condition shouldn't be difficult to enforce.

Comment: Please will you explain the line 'const auto & arr =  *parr'? Is it providing a reference to the array?

Comment: Actually `const` is unnecessary, it's just my habit of declaring as `const` the things I don't change. As for the reference: it's just a way of simplifying notation.  After `auto & arr =  *parr;` the compiler is obliged to understand `arr` as `(*parr)`, so you don't need to use obscure notation like `(void*) &(*parr)`. It's far simpler and easier to understand to use `(void*) &arr` instead. The code produced by the compiler should be exactly the same. In other words: in C++ references (&) are most often used to pass function arguments but sometimes to simplify notation.

Comment: In even simpler words: placement new forces you to use pointers. But we avoid using pointers if we don't REALLY need them. Here, by using reference, you can forget that you have access to `std::array`  via a pointer and consider it to  be a "normal" array, with a "value" syntax (no need for `*`).

Answer (score 0):

For embedded code, two simple solutions spring to mind:

1. Declare `extern int myArray[1234] ;` and then define `myArray` (or rather its mangled form) in your linker definition file.
2. Define a macro: `#define myArray ((int*)0xC0DEFACE)`

The first solution is for the purists; the second is for the pragmatists.